# How to allow multiDatesPicker in wp admin post type?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

The WP custom post type already used jquery UI datepicker , but I need to add multidatepicker for on field. I have added

```
function pw_loading_scripts_wrong() {
    echo '<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js">';
}
add_action('admin_head', 'pw_loading_scripts_wrong');
```

and

```
$(function() {
      $( ".datepicker").multiDatesPicker({
        minDate: 0, showButtonPanel: true, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true          
            , onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { inst.settings.defaultDate = dateText; }

      });
    });
```

but still not working. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

```
try now this code
<?php  function load_requirements() 
{
        wp_register_script('mdp', 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js');
        wp_enqueue_script('mdp');
}
add_action('admin_head', 'load_requirements');?>


 jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
 {
   $('.datepicker').multiDatesPicker();
 });
```